# Can I "catch" a redirect executed by a script, with javascript eventListeners?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an HTML page that includes only a script tag, I don't control the script and I can't change it (so I can't fire my custom event for example). 
The script ends with a redirect (using `window.location`).

Is there a way to add a new script to the page that will listen to the page events and "catch" the redirect (actually it's better for me to catch the new loaded document)?
Something like:

```
window.addEventListener('redirected', function() {
  // do staff
});
```

(I know there is no "redirected" event, it's just for the example).

It's very important to make it clear that the redirect isn't caused by an anchor click or back/forward button click, so I can't use events like click or popstate.

Comment: Alas `window.location` cannot be overridden like for example window.write can

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [onpagehide](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpagehide.asp) event or the [onunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) event, both of which occur when the user navigates away from the page.

However, if you wish to interfere or prevent the redirection itself, [onbeforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at :

- unload function [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) or [mozilla developper network](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)
- [beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) function for sending a final XMLHttpRequest